# How to calculate the mod value of a rational/irrational value?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We have a course in network security this semester and we are being taught RSA algorithm.

I came across a typical math problem that I was unable to solve here.

$$D*E \equiv 1 \mod{\phi(n)}$$

This became $$D \equiv E^{-1}  \mod{\phi(n)}$$ How do you solve this ???

My lect gave this specific example

$$D \equiv 7^{-1} \mod{160}$$ and the solution for $D$ was $23$! How did she arrive at this.

Comment: To have your Latex render, enclose it in dollar signs \$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$7D = 1 \mod 160$

**Sol'n**

> $7D = 1 \mod 160$ and $D = 23 \Longrightarrow 23*7 \mod 160$ satisfies this.

Comment: I know 23 satisfies the equation :| I wanted to know how did she arrive at 23. Is there a non trial and error way of solving this ?

Comment: HINT: Divide 160 by 7 in the integer ring.

Answer (score 0):

D ≡ (mod 160)/7 which is equal to 7D ≡ 1 * (mod 160)

This type of question is a Congruence Relation.

This means that (1 mod 160) = (7D mod 160)

(1 mod 160) simplifies to 1 so that means that (7D mod 160) = 1

This means that 7D/160 must have a remainder of 1

You know that 1 is a possible answer but that would create a decimal when divided by 7 and RSA numbers do not do decimals.

The equation will usually get the number just above but also closest to the modular divisor which in this case is 160+1 or 161.

161/7 = 23

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgvA3z-vOzc
Check this out. The problem can be solved using extended Euclidean Algorithm to be precise. For smaller numbers, the answers already mentioned are sufficient.